# Objective-c and Cocotron

Tags: objective-c

Is it truly a good API which can actually be used to develop applications for the iphone in Linux? The main reason I ask is because I really want to learn Objective-c, but also be able to port it to something as well.

Comment: Not really Obj C related, but depending on the app Javascript and HTML are a legitimate tool.  Just add a UIWebView.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm not really a fan of Javascript. I do enough Php/HTML dev at work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. To develop an app for iOS, you need a Mac. The main development environment called XCode only runs on a Mac, and without XCode it is a serious pain to install the compiled app to the iOS devices to perform a test-run.

So, if you want to develop an app for iOS, and distribute the resulting app to the wider world (for non jailbroken devices), just give up hope and buy a Mac.

Now, if you just want to learn Objective-C, as NSResponder says, [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) is a good place, which replicates the OpenStep specification (which comes before NeXTStep took over Apple). [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) is on the other hand is a port of the main APIs of later OS X to Windows. (I don't know if Cocotron is ported to Linux or not.)

But you also need to understand that both GNUStep and Cocotron cover only Foundation (non-GUI parts of the Objective-C framework) and AppKit (desktop GUI parts of the Objective-C), not the UIKit (mobile GUI parts of the Objective-C). AppKit and UIKit are rather similar, so knowing one helps learning the other.